# Artifactory and Nuget for Visual Studio Team services

Tags: nuget, artifactory, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have a project where we need to integrate nuget packages from local and remote sources in to Jfrog Artifactory. The problem im having is with Visual studio team services as it does not pull the local nuget packages, and it shows a login error. although it does get the nuget.org from our remote repository.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up a Personal Access Token and store that in Artifactory before it can access VSTS feeds. [See the docs here.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/auth#personal-access-tokens)